# "export default from" doesn't work with Babel React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, babeljs

I use `react` to build my library of components. I need to have an `index.js` to import all components in one place.

Something like this:

```
MyComponents/
  Button.js
  Label.js
  index.js
```

Inside the `index.js` I tried to do next:

```
// this export nothing
export {default} from './Button';
// this tells me about syntax error
export default from './Button';
```

I found only this solution that works

```
import Button from './Button';
export default Button;
```

But I found that some React Component libraries uses syntax that I mentioned above (`export default from './Button'`) - and it works somehow. Looks like they use some `babel-plugin-transform-*` to do this.

Please find me to find how to transform my two lines of import export to one line of `export ... from ...`. Thank you.

P.S. In the end I need to do this: `import Button from './MyComponents';`

Comment: Please try `export {default as Button} from './Button'`.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work. It compiles, but don't allow to import a Button from the module.

Comment: I have replicated your example and `export default from './Button'` works for me. Compiles and displays correctly. I use following Babel presets: `"es2015", "stage-0", "react"`. Can you show me your Babel/Webpack configuration?
[See a screenshot here](http://imgur.com/luoRBEl)

Comment: Hi. I don't use `stage-0` or `stage-1` because this is an experimental features. It may be a reason.

Comment: Oh yes. Finally I found a description of this proposal here: https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-export-default-from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use this construction:

```
export default from './Button';
```

we need to use [preset-stage-1](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/).

### How to use

1. `npm install babel-preset-stage-1 --save-dev`
2. edit file `package.json` and add `stage-1` to the `presets` section in `babel`.

#### Example of `package.json`

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-1",
    "react"
  ]
},
```

### More info

It's a proposal to the ECMAScript - https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-export-default-from *(still in review)*.

Answer (score 11):

Use the following syntax:

```
File: layouts/index.js

export {default as Flex} from './flex'
export {default as Grid} from './grid'
export {default as Dock} from './dock'
```

Then you can use

```
import { Dock, Grid } from 'layouts'
```

or

```
import layouts from 'layouts'

<layouts.Flex >...</layouts.Flex>
```

---

In order to export nested indices created by the above method you can use `export *` syntax:

```
File: icons/index.js

export * as action from './action';
export * as alert from './alert';
export * as av from './av';
```

Usage:

```
import * as icons from 'material/icons'

<icons.action.Close />
```

Comment: Sorry, but I need to use `import Button from './MyComponents';` instead of `import {Button} from './MyComponents';`

Comment: And with asterisk it also doesn't work - SyntaxError: `export * as Button from './Button';`

Comment: You can always `import Button from './MyComponents/Button'` if you want to only import the Button, which is more semantically correct.

Comment: You are right, `export *` doesn't work in this case. It only works for nested indices exported by the above syntax. I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: My project structure has a bigger hierarchy. It's my very simplified example to understand how can I correctly use imports in the `index.js` file to use per-component directory.

Comment: If you really want to use `import Button from './MyComponents';` then how can you import `Button` and the `Label` from `MyComponents` without using `import {Button, Label} from './MyComponents'` syntax?

I think two imports like this won't work in the same module: 

`import Button from './MyComponents'`
`import Label from './MyComponents'`

 Am I right or wrong?

Comment: I see that guys somehow do this and it works. Please se this: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/AppBar/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Just use `export * from "./Button";` to export the whole module. This will help your use case.

Unfortunately, there is no one-line syntax to export just the default of another module.

Comment: In the Button.js I use this export: `export default Button;` and as you can see from my description - I can import it and export. But question is how to do this in only one string.

Comment: See this for example: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/AppBar/index.js

Comment: try export * from "./Button"; this will export everything along with default. there is no solution to just export deafult in one line. hope this helps. I updated my answer

Comment: Looks like you totally not understand my question. And `import Button from './Button';` is mentioned in my original question, if you will read it carefully.

Comment: i understood ur question there is no available solution to export just the default import of another module in "one line". but u can do export * from "./Button"; this will work perfectly

Comment: In ES6 it doesn't work, because it export nothing (you can try to translate file from ES6 with this proposed solution). You will find that `export * from ...` will not add `exports.default` and `module.exports` in the resulting copied file (ES5).

Comment: @AntonDanilchenko what u want is not possible then

Comment: Please see my link that I added in the second comment to your answer.

Comment: @AntonDanilchenko got it. are u using babel-plugin-add-module-exports?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I use it. Can you check it locally and then give me a correct answer?

Comment: ok i got ur problem the button module doesnt have a named export. by which babel-plugin-add-module-exports will treat it as a commonJs module which makes it ineligible to do a direct default export